# ice:dataExporter Exporting to pdf issues

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, icefaces, jsf-1.2

I am trying to export some data displayed in my datatable using the  component present in the ICEFaces 1.8 components showcase.

In the doc, they have mentioned to import iText.jar (preferably v2.1.7) to make it working. Hence I have imported the iText.jar (v2.1.7). But the export to pdf is not working.

The other two (i.e. csv and excel) are working perfrctly, only the pdf export is not working.

Not sure along with adding the iText in build path, something else is also needed or not for making it working :(

kindly let me know about this.

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: No. No error message in the console. A new window pop-up came but after that nothing happened. The URL for that window is: `http://localhost:8050/DataTableExporterDemo/block/resource/MjA2MzYyNzMxOA==/no-data`

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc, the ice:dataExporter will only support csv or excel format.
However, the ace:dataExporter can provide a pdf file, at least on my case.
Could you provide more code to confirm?

Comment: The demo for generating `pdf` using `ice:dataExporter` provided in the icefaces 1.8 components showcase from this URL: `http://component-showcase.icesoft.org/component-showcase/showcase.iface`. In the DataExporter demo, they have provided the option for the `pdf` also. If you check the description in the same screen(2nd tab),  they have clearly mentioned about `pdf` aldo but it needs an additional jar i.e. `iText jar`. Please let me know if you have used this earlier.

Answer (score 0):

In order to support exporting files in PDF format, the iText library version 2.1.7 (itext-2.1.7.jar) must be in the classpath of the application, typically in the WEB-INF/lib folder. For licensing reasons, the iText library is not included in the ICEfaces distribution bundles. Also note that if the itext jar is copied into the icefaces/lib/ace directory, it will be included in the showcase sample application (showcase.war) when it is built using ant.